# smack xmpp mam implementation

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I made some research and tried several suggestion found on net to get the MAM response from my openfire server. 
 This is the IQ packet I am sending to server

```
<iq id="v7sWB-10" type="set">
   <query xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:0" queryid="e8f7a935-4c49-4955-b7ee-57a832be7da9">
      <x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit">
         <field var="FORM_TYPE" type="hidden">
            <value>urn:xmpp:mam:0</value>
         </field>
         <field var="with">
            <value>xxxxx@xxxxxyy.com</value>
         </field>
      </x>
   </query>
</iq>
```

following is the smack response I am getting from my server as log:

```
<iq type="result" id="v7sWB-10" to="xxxxx@xxxx.com/smack-0.03822310071941204"/>
<message to="xxxx@txxxxxx.com/smack-0.03822310071941204">
<result xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:0" id="1" queryid="e8f7a935-4c49-4955-b7ee-57a832be7da9">
<forwarded xmlns="urn:xmpp:forward:0"><delay xmlns="urn:xmpp:delay" stamp="2016-05-31T08:42:38.837Z"/>
<message xmlns="" from="xxxx@xxxx.com/converse.js-30995" to="xxxx@xxxx.com" type="chat" id="6bdf41ad-f37d-431b-acdc-4475af480db3">
<body>test1111</body>
<active xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates">
</active>
</message>
</forwarded>
</result>
</message>
```

Following is the code of my filter :

```
PacketListener packetListener = new PacketListener() {
        @Override
        public void processPacket(Stanza packet) throws SmackException.NotConnectedException {

            Log.e("message ",packet.toXML().toString());
            if (packet instanceof Message) {
                Message message = (Message) packet;
                String chatMessage = message.getBody();
            }
        }
    };


    private void regiSterPackateListner() {
        PacketExtensionFilter filter = new PacketExtensionFilter(MamElements.MamResultExtension.ELEMENT,MamElements.NAMESPACE);
        try {
            if (packetListener != null) {
                //Avoid adding multiple packetlistner
                connection.removePacketListener(packetListener);
            }
            connection.addPacketListener(packetListener, filter);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

but the result I am getting from server is which lacks the forwarded and delay tags:

```
<message to='xxxx@xxxx.com/smack-0.03822310071941204'>
<result xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:0'>
</result>
</message>
```

What am I doing wrong ? and how to create a filter to parse such a packet?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: yes, partially. Couldn't make the mam work perfectly, but now I can get the messages inside my filter class. The issue was with the provider manager.